# Voltage and Resistance definition

Tags: potential, electrical-resistance, terminology, voltage, definition

Consider a wire of lenght $L$ and transversal area $A$ that it isn't an ideal conductor, but follows Ohm's Law. After a few computations we have

$$-\Delta\phi = \rho\frac{L}{A} I $$

where $\rho$ is electrical resistivity. Note that $\Delta\phi < 0$.

My question is if voltage and resistance are defined as:

1) $V =-\Delta\phi$ (positive) and $ R = \rho\frac{L}{A}$ (positive)

or

2) $V = \Delta\phi$ (negative) and $ R =-\rho\frac{L}{A}$ (negative).

Supporting 1): Voltage is the work done by **the Electric Field** to move a charge from $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{B}$. And since the difference of potential is the work done by **an external force** against the Eletric Field from $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{B}$, I think this definition makes sence.

Supporting 2): I've read in some places (for example, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316450/explain-voltage)) that voltage is the difference of potential. I could have misunderstood what they meant by that. Also, when I was thought this, I've never been explicitly told what was voltage.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452935/why-isnt-there-a-minus-sign-in-ohms-law-v-ir?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resistance $R$ is positive. So (2) is incorrect. The sign on $V$ is a matter of convention and depends on which direction you call positive for $I$

Comment: Thank you for answering! In this example, to keep it simple, if I call I positive in the direction of $\mathbf{J}$ (i.e $\hat{n}$ is in the direction of $\mathbf{J}$ so that $I = \int_{S} \,\mathbf{J}\cdot\hat{n}\,dS > 0$), $ V = -\Delta\phi$?

Comment: Yes, because current goes in the direction of decreasing $\phi$

Answer (score 0):

The word voltage is used because electrical potential is measured in volts. Similarly mileage for distance travelled by a car. Potential difference is a technically more correct term than voltage.

Your definition 1 is correct, though it is sometimes called emf (curly E - I don't know the MathJax) to distinguish it from a measured voltage.

Unless you are careful the + and - signs can cause problems. The difference between two numbers is the larger minus the smaller, so it is positive, and in the same way the potential difference across a battery or a resistor is normally stated as a positive number. Usually if you follow the direction of the current an emf is a rise in potential. The exception might be if there is another potential source in the circuit. There is a drop in potential in the direction of the current through a resistance.